# remove extra space in spark button

Tags: flash, button, actionscript, flex-spark

How is it possible to remove extra space in spark button?

[image: a busy cat]
<sub>(source: [turboimagehost.com](http://s4d3.turboimagehost.com/t/11861499_button.png))</sub>

So i need the image or text starts exactly with left border of the button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to define a new skin for your Button.
CSS:

```
s|Button {
   skinClass:ClassReference("skins.MySkin");
}
```

MySkin.mxml will be a copy of `Flex\frameworks\projects\spark\src\spark\skins\spark\ButtonSkin.mxml`

Then you can change the value `left="10"` for `labelDisplay` or add a `BitmapImage` called `iconDisplay` and set its `left` value.

Comment: For label it works fine! but for icon not :(
I have:
    <s:Button x="3" y="145" id="test_Btn1" icon="Image.png"/>
and skin:
        <s:BitmapImage left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"></s:BitmapImage>

I still have a space.

Comment: Have you set your BitmapImage's id to "labelDisplay" ?

Comment: yes, "labelDisplay" generates error: Error: Attempting to initialize inherited property 'labelDisplay' of type 'spark.core.IDisplayText' with value of incompatible type 'spark.primitives.BitmapImage'.  
if I use >source="@Embed('t1.png')"  
if skin, it works fine

Comment: I get: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference   

With simply id="icon" I has no effect

Comment: Mmh sorry, I can't tell without more info about the error. Here is what states the Flex reference: iconDisplay:BitmapImage
Required: false Part Type: Static
A skin part that defines an optional icon for the button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11314/discussion-between-max-and-kodiak)